# Forced nonlinear oscillator - analytical methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

This is an example from [Kovacic & Brennan (2011)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CPJSBA). Consider the following equation of motion for a forced, non-linear oscillator (Duffing's equation):

$$
\ddot x + 2 \zeta \dot x + \alpha x + \gamma x^3 = F \cos \Omega t,
$$
where $\zeta, \alpha, \gamma, F$ and $\Omega$ are parameters. We assume "the steady-state harmonic solution" as

$$
x = Y\cos{(\Omega t - \theta)}.
$$

My goal is to obtain the following equation for $Y$:

$$
Y^2 = \frac{F^2}{4\zeta^2\Omega^2 + \left( \Omega^2 - \alpha - 
%
\frac{3}{4}\gamma Y^2 \right)^2}.
$$

This is done by 1) substituting the second equation into the first, and 2) equating the coefficients of $\sin\Omega t$ and $\cos\Omega t$ from both sides.

The substitution part seems straightforward, but I can't quite wrap my head around the last step. Especially the "$\cos(\Omega t-\theta)$" on the right hand side is causing headaches.

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Hint: expand $\cos(\Omega t - \theta) = \cos(\Omega t) \cos(\theta) + \sin(\Omega t) \sin(\theta)$.

Comment: What are you going to do with the $\cos{3 \Omega t}$ and $\sin{3 \Omega t}$ terms on the left hand side?  Ignore them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is simple differentiation and substitution...except that the cubic term makes things a little hairy.  First thing is to expand the cosine term as

$$\cos{(\Omega t-\theta)} = \cos{\Omega t} \cos{\theta} + \sin{\Omega t} \sin{\theta}$$

Now differentiate and plug in.  The linear terms involving the derivative are simple and I'll just list them here:

$$\ddot{x} + 2 \zeta \dot{x} + \alpha x = Y \left [ \left ( -\Omega^2 \cos{\theta} - 2 \zeta \Omega \sin{\theta} + \alpha \cos{\theta}  \right ) \cos{\Omega t} \\+ \left (-\Omega^2 \sin{\theta} + 2 \zeta \Omega \cos{\theta} + \alpha \sin{\theta}  \right ) \sin{\Omega t} \right ]  $$

The cubic piece is expanded as usual:

$$\gamma x^3 = \gamma Y^3 (\cos^3{\Omega t} \cos^3{\theta} + 3 \cos^2{\Omega t} \sin{\Omega t} \cos^2{\theta} \sin{\theta} + 3 \sin^2{\Omega t} \cos{\Omega t} \sin^2{\theta} \cos{\theta}+ \sin^3{\Omega t} \sin^3{\theta}$$

Now we do not want powers of the sines and cosines, but rather linear terms.  Use the fact that

$$\cos{3 y} = 4 \cos^3{y} - 3 \cos{y}$$
$$\sin{3 y} = 3 \sin{y} - 4 \sin^3{y}$$

and, doing some rearranging, get that

$$\gamma x^3 = \gamma Y^3 \left [\frac{3}{4} \cos{\theta} \cos{\Omega t} + \frac{3}{4} \sin{\theta} \sin{\Omega t} \\+ \frac{1}{4} \cos{\theta}\left (\cos^2{\theta} - 3 \sin^2{\theta} \right ) \cos{3 \Omega t} + \frac{1}{4} \sin{\theta}\left (3 \cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta} \right ) \sin{3 \Omega t} \right ]$$

Note that the $3 \Omega$ terms represent the frequency multiplication induced by nonlinear terms.  We will ignore these terms because...(e.g., $\gamma$ is small, etc. etc.).  What we are left with is

$$Y \left [ \left ( \left (\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2\right ) \cos{\theta} - 2 \zeta \Omega \sin{\theta}  \right ) \cos{\Omega t} \\+ \left ( \left (\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2\right ) \sin{\theta} + 2 \zeta \Omega \cos{\theta}  \right ) \sin{\Omega t} \right ]  = F \cos{\Omega t}$$

Now we simply eliminate $\theta$ by setting the coefficient of $\sin{\Omega t}$ to zero:

$$\left (\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2\right ) \sin{\theta} + 2 \zeta \Omega \cos{\theta}  =0$$

or

$$\tan{\theta} = -\frac{ 2 \zeta \Omega}{\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2}$$

which means that, to within a sign,

$$\cos{\theta} = \frac{\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2}{\sqrt{4 \zeta^2 \Omega^2 + \left (\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2 \right )^2}} $$

$$\sin{\theta} = -\frac{2 \zeta \Omega}{\sqrt{4 \zeta^2 \Omega^2 + \left (\alpha-\Omega^2 + \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2 \right )^2}} $$

and therefore, plugging these values into the equation for the coefficient of $\cos{\Omega t}$, we get that, within a sign:

$$Y = \frac{F}{\sqrt{4 \zeta^2 \Omega^2 + \left (\Omega^2 -\alpha - \frac{3}{4} \gamma Y^2 \right )^2}} $$

The posted equation for $Y$ follows.

Comment: Well, *that* certainly had plenty of *hair*! ;)

Comment: To Ron Gordon:  hey, *you're* the one who said it was hairy, not me!  Anyway, I've seen a lot worse meself,! ;)

Comment: @RobertLewis: I said a *little* hairy.

Comment: To Ron Gordon:  what, perchance, is the metric of hairiness?  Anyway, I didn't mean "worse" in any opprobriative sense!   In sooth, your answer is indeed not overly hairy, but adequately so! ;)

Comment: @RobertLewis: just being argumentative, I guess.  I would say, at first thought, that a good metric of hairiness involves a measure of pain induced by the application and rapid removal of duct tape on a specified surface, but unfortunately that just left icky tape residue on my monitor.

Comment: Now THIS is math: "We will ignore these terms because...(e.g., γ is small, etc. etc.)." Physicist? ;-)

Comment: @trolle3000: guilty as charged.  Although, keep in mind, that you merely wanted to know where that equation came from.  I did not claim any level of approximation or validity - I just conjectured how that equation was derived.  A really good exercise would be to assess that validity.  Under what conditions can we ignore the $3 \Omega$ terms?  And how about that equation for $Y$?  Must we solve a cubic in $Y^2$ to get its value?  I think this solution provides more questions than answers.  That said, I hope you understood how to manage that sort of algebra.

Comment: It was a great help, thanks. I've just verified the validity numerically - the solution trajectories of Duffing's equation converges to one attractor when there is one solution, and one of two attractors *depending on initial conditions* when there are three solutions (one is unstable). So it works!